# Will my cat survive after eating a frog?

Tags: cats, frogs

My cat ate a frog yesterday and he is not eating anything now. I have the following concerns:

1. Will he survive?
2. Is the frog poisonous?
3. Why is he not eating anything now?

Comment: What type of frog? Most are not poisonous, but some could be. In any case, if your cat is not eating or otherwise is unwell, then he needs to go to a vet. These questions cannot be answered over the internet.

Comment: It was a normal small green frog

Comment: ok, probably not toxic then, though I'm sure in some parts of the world there are toxic small green frogs. Whether your cat is unwell from the frog or something else, he needs to see a vet.

Comment: ok sir, Thanks alot, I guess vet is now the only option.

Comment: Where you are? In a lot of places there are simply no poisonous frogs (poisonous ones are rare in the first place).

Comment: It's 19 hours after you posted. How is the cat doing?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, your cat will survive, my cat has eaten lots of frogs, toads, and salamanders and sometimes she loses her appetite for a few hours after eating them.

If your cat shows signs of poisoning, stop reading this and get your cat to the vet **now**.

Symptoms to look for can be found in the article "[How Can I Tell If My Cat Has Been Poisoned](https://www.dunnellonanimalhospital.com/site/blog/2021/10/30/cat-poisoned)".

Frogs will be poisonous if their diet contains poisons but normally the levels are low, toads are often more poisonous than frogs living in the same area. (See also "[Do Cats Eat Frogs?](https://www.tuxedo-cat.co.uk/do-cats-eat-frogs/))

Most amphibians, reptiles, and birds carry salmonella and this can make your cat feel bad for a few hours, if your cat stops eating for more than a day it is an **emergency** and you need to get your cat to the vet.

A couple of things to think about:

If your cat eat amphibians, reptiles, or birds it will get internal parasites (worms) so you will have to treat your cat against this at regular intervals.

Amphibians/reptiles/birds are protected species in many areas so by letting your cat hunt you might be breaking the law.

Comment: Treating the cat against internal parasites periodically is good for any cat that walks outside, no matter if you see them hunting or not.

Comment: It should be noted that if you live near the Pacific coast of North America, you definitely shouldn't let your cat eat salamanders. Orange bellied newts would be deadly.

Comment: It is impressive how much competent the cat may be in regard to potentially dangerous prey. Where I live, we simply don't have anything poisonous, but I was impressed how Greek cats (even young, inexperienced ones) precisely stay away of dragonfish (Trachinus draco).